# is there any method to Insert Data To Database with Looping

Tags: java, sqlite, loops

Recently, I had loop 1000 000 row of data to my SQLite database. It took me **2367** minutes (39 hours) for my Netbeans compiler to finish process the data.

I used a `for` loop for the looping process. I wonder if there are any efficient and faster practice for the program to loop much faster than that.

Currently, I am using this simple for loop as my code:

```
for(i = 0; 1 < 1000000; i ++){

//code to insert 1 row of data to sqlite database

}
```

From my research from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/), while loop and iterator loop will not result any significant performance compare to for loop.

Comment: Could you use a [batch](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/) approach?

Comment: well, i think i can try that. ill update the post when i get the result

Comment: Did you try this link ? http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/

Comment: oh thank you for the link, i havent try that yet,the article really interesting, surely ill read it. thank ranjit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you are trying to create a connection for every loop, or trying to execute the insert statement for every iteration, consider you using batch. Insert every 5000 or 10000. batch insert:

```
String sql = "insert into employee (name, city, phone) values (?, ?, ?)";
Connection connection = new getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

for (Employee employee: employees) {

    ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
    ps.setString(2, employee.getCity());
    ps.setString(3, employee.getPhone());
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: yes i try to execute insert every iteration. the process was really time consuming. thank you for showing me this. this answer will do, thank you @melt321

Comment: @beNice please set as accepted answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The for-loop isn't expensive in itself, but if you are many inserting rows into a database, you should use transactions, which will group the insert calls into one call. Otherwise, there is a significant I/O cost in adding 1,000,000 rows separately.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT ...;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```